# Jenkins multibranch pipeline Scan without execution

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

Is it possible to Scan a Multibranch Pipeline to detect the branches with a `Jenkinsfile`, but without the pipeline execution?

My projects have different branches and I don't want that all the children pipelines branches with a Jenkinsfile to start to execute when I launch a build scan from the parent pipeline multibranch.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In your **Branch Sources** section you can add a Property named Suppress automatic SCM triggering.

This prevents Jenkins from building everything with an `Jenkinsfile`.

Comment: ohhhhh! thanks you very much!. this is which i need :)

Comment: This seems to not only prevent jobs from executing as result of a scan (which is what you want), but also prevents them from executing as part of a commit to the source branch (which you probably don't want).  In other words, this change blocks any Git Hooks from triggering a build.

Comment: @AndrewCruickshank any way to do this but keep the web hooks working??

Comment: It doesn't block a git hook if you use curl + auth token  to trigger a build.

Comment: I can't find this, is it deprecated? What is the alternative?

Comment: Just for clarification, Gudgip's workaround is not the same as a webhook--meaning, Andrew is correct, as the docs for that class show: " * Suppresses builds due to either {@link BranchIndexingCause} or {@link BranchEventCause}.
 * The purpose of this property is to prevent triggering builds resulting from the <em>detection</em> * of changes in the underlying SCM." (https://github.com/jenkinsci/branch-api-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/branch/NoTriggerBranchProperty.java)

Comment: @FadelTrivandiDipantara  I am facing same issue. It's deprecated. What's the workaround?

Comment: Nice explanation here on the deprecation : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-56231?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

Comment: This is great! I have a multibranch repo pipeline on my local machine, which i use to test before i push up to my org's github. When i create new branches, delete branches, etc, i have to use the Scan to find/delete them. The scan results in _every_ branch running the pipe. With this new behavior configured, i can scan the repo at will without triggering any builds! Specifically: in `Property Strategy` -> `all branches get the same...` -> configure as `.*` and select `matching branches suppress builds` . other options up to you.

Comment: @MaxCascone, how do I set this up so that `feature/*` branches builds are suppressed when indexing, but the rest are not suppressed?

Comment: @ChrisF if you set the filter in the `Property Strategy -> all branches get the same...` to `feature/*`, that should block `feature/*` branches from triggering, while allowing others to trigger.

Comment: @MaxCascone thanks! I was making it too complicated.

Answer (score 10):

Also, you can do it programatically

```
import jenkins.branch.*
import jenkins.model.Jenkins


for (f in Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.class)) {
  if (f.parent instanceof jenkins.branch.OrganizationFolder) {
    continue;
  }
  for (s in f.sources) {
    def prop = new jenkins.branch.NoTriggerBranchProperty();
    def propList = [prop] as jenkins.branch.BranchProperty[];
    def strategy = new jenkins.branch.DefaultBranchPropertyStrategy(propList);
    s.setStrategy(strategy);
  }

  f.computation.run()
}
```

This is a Groovy snippet you can execute in Jenkins, it's gonna do the scanning but will not start new "builds" for all discovered branches.

Comment: this is a groovy snippet you can execute in Jenkins
it gonna do the scanning but will not start new "builds" for all discovered branches

Comment: where do I put this?

Comment: @FadelTrivandiDipantara
basically you put it into $JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d folder and then when you start your Jenkins - it gonna execute all scripts from this folder.

if you already have a jenkins up and running you can go to Jenkins -> Script Console and try to execute that code there.

Comment: can be executed also in the Jenkins Admin > Nodes > Master and open **Script Console**

Comment: can this be added to Github folder that mentions all Jenkinsfiles? I have groovy scripts there.

Comment: Calling `f.scheduleBuild()` instead of `f.computation.run()` runs it in background, and so it allows the script to finish for large amount of jobs.

Comment: Very cool script! How can this be modified so it only suppresses builds for certain branches, e.g., all `feature/*` branches?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using job-dsl you could simply do this and it will scan everything without actually running the build the first time you index.

```
organizationFolder('Some folder name') {
  buildStrategies {
    skipInitialBuildOnFirstBranchIndexing()
  }
}
```

Comment: do you need to have organizations or folders? how does it work? what should I use instead of "Some folder name"?

Comment: No, you can probably find buildStrategies other places, check the documentation on your instance, it should hold all available options. "Some folder name" is simply a placeholder, it will name a folder in Jenkins to organise your builds.

Comment: I got error an error with this. `ERROR: (script, line 13) No such property: skipInitialBuildOnFirstBranchIndexing for class: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.workflow.BuildStrategiesContext`

Comment: @scav I got this error using your answer javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.workflow.BuildStrategiesContext.skipInitialBuildOnFirstBranchIndexing()

Comment: plugin `basic-branch-build-strategies` is required

Answer (score 4):

To add to @Stqs's answer, you could also set `noTriggerBranchProperty` it using Job DSL plugin, e.g.:

```
multibranchPipelineJob('example') {
  ...
  branchSources {
    branchSource {
      ...
      strategy {
        defaultBranchPropertyStrategy {
          props {
            // Suppresses the normal SCM commit trigger coming from branch indexing
            noTriggerBranchProperty()
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: `noTriggerBranchProperty` is doing the job but blocks webhooks
Is it possibly to have `noTriggerBranchProperty` together with webhook triggers?

Answer (score 3):

```
organizationFolder('my-folder') {

  buildStrategies {
     buildRegularBranches()
     buildChangeRequests {
       ignoreTargetOnlyChanges true
       ignoreUntrustedChanges false
     }
   }
}
```

Note: plugin `basic-branch-build-strategies` is required

REFERENCES:

- https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-63799
- http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/JobDSL-an-example-of-configuring-a-bitbucket-source-trait-of-bitbucketForkDiscovery-in-the-multibrand-td5014968.html#a5015085

Answer (score 3):

After much struggle I've found this solution, it should only avoid triggering the build when branch indexing and not disable automatic build after commit. Just add it in the first stage of your project:

```
when {
    not {
        expression {
            def causes = currentBuild.getBuildCauses()
            String causesClass = causes._class[0]
            return causesClass.contains('BranchIndexingCause')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jenkinsfiles to define your pipelines (you should be!), add the `overrideIndexTriggers(false)` option.

```java
pipeline {
  options {
    overrideIndexTriggers(false) // disable branch indexing build trigger
  }
```