# Prevent Jenkins multibranch pipeline from triggering builds for new branches

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have a multibranch pipeline job for deploying an application in IIS. Because of it, I cannot run the job (that deploys a new version of the application) when new branches are discovered.

I need to configure the trigger only to discover new branches and do not trigger the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **Branch Sources** section you can add a Property named Suppress automatic SCM triggering.

This prevents Jenkins from building everything with an `Jenkinsfile`.

More [Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004636/jenkins-multibranch-pipeline-scan-without-execution)

Comment: Jenkins was not showing this option to me. I discovered that the plugin basic-branch-build-strategies hides this option. So I disabled the basic-branch-build-strategies and the option appeared. This was exactly what I needed... thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Jenkinsfile to define your pipe, add the following to the `options` block:

```java
pipeline {
...
  options {
    overrideIndexTriggers(false)
  }
}
```

While the syntax is a bit opaque, it will cause the pipe to not run when triggered by indexing.