# BitBucket webhook triggers *all* Jenkins multibranch pipelines, even those who have that setting disabled

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

*Context:* We have a Jenkins 2.361.3 server and a local Bitbucket server with webhooks (on Push) that trigger multibranch pipeline jobs (declarative jenkinsfile mode) on Jenkins for every repo push. This works fine when we have a single multibranch pipeline job on Jenkins: the build is triggered for the correct branch.

*New scenario:* We want a second 'nightly' multibranch pipeline job on the same Jenkins server for the same Bitbucket repo, which we want to trigger on a fixed time every day for every branch that exists at that time. It should not trigger for repo pushes.

*Actions taken:* We created a second multibranch pipeline job, similar to the first one but now with a cron trigger in the jenkinsfile and this setting disabled: "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket":

[image: Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket setting disabled]

This setting is still enabled for the initial job.

*Expectations:*

1. On a repo push, only the initial job is triggered. The nightly job does nothing.
2. When the cron time hits, the night job is triggered.

*Actual:*

1. On a repo push, both jobs are triggered. (also after Jenkins restart)
2. Additionally, the cron trigger works as expected.

***Question:* How to configure this system so that a repo push only triggers the initial job and not the nightly job?**

It looks like the combination of BitBucket plugin (v223) and Multibranch Pipeline plugin (v716) does not adhere to the "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket" setting.

*Experiments performed:*

1. Disabling the "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket" setting for both jobs (and restarting Jenkins) --> both jobs are still triggered by a repo push
2. Remove the webhook from BitBucket and configure 'polling SCM' for both jobs --> this works but polling feels suboptimal and adds performance hits to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved it using the “Suppress automatic SCM triggering” property in the ‘Branch Sources’ section of the Jenkins configure page for the job, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44065489/3175881).

The ‘Scan multibranch pipeline trigger’ setting only controls the scans (even though the text says ‘build’), and this will cause a trigger. The Suppress property lets a certain job *ignore* a webhook or scan trigger. And then the job is only triggered by its cron-trigger, which is what we wanted.

[image]