# Jenkins multibranch pipeline Scan without execution v2?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Daniel Majano posted [Jenkins multibranch pipeline Scan without execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004636/jenkins-multibranch-pipeline-scan-without-execution), and @Stqs's answer is the one that I liked best, which is not the chosen answer, is this snippet

```
import jenkins.branch.*
import jenkins.model.Jenkins


for (f in Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.class)) {
  if (f.parent instanceof jenkins.branch.OrganizationFolder) {
    continue;
  }
  for (s in f.sources) {
    def prop = new jenkins.branch.NoTriggerBranchProperty();
    def propList = [prop] as jenkins.branch.BranchProperty[];
    def strategy = new jenkins.branch.DefaultBranchPropertyStrategy(propList);
    s.setStrategy(strategy);
  }

  f.computation.run()
}
```

How can I modify this code to only affect, say, `feature/*` branches? In other words, I still want my multi-branch pipeline jobs to scan and execute, **except** for `feature/*` branches.